# QGIS: Prevent the Primary Key from incrementing when feature won’t be saved

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-3

So, I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS DB attached to my QGIS project (MacOS, 3.10.).

I start adding a feature and cancel the process w/o saving the form. When adding another feature my primary key increments by one even though the **last** feature wasn't saved.

Is this avoidable? Meaning: Can I prevent the PK from being incremented when canceling a feature addition?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
<QGIS> | Settings | Options... | Data Sources | Data source handling
```

and see if **`Evaluate default values`** is active; if so, **deactivate it**.

QGIS can either request the default value (as per column definition) **while editing (option active)**, or read the default value definition and pass it (or simply `NULL`) **at save time (option inactive)**!
A `nextval` call to a PostgreSQL *Sequence* ( the default action/value for `SERIAL` types) will increment **regardless of transaction outcome**!

Comment: `Evaluate default values` was already deactivated. But if I understand you correctly what I want is not possible since `nextval` will be called even if I don’t save the form, right? I thought it might be possible since I also have a GeoDjango app connected to the same db and cancelling a form there does not increment the PK.

Comment: @JohnZombie yeah, as a matter of fact, I cannot seem to change the option permanently anyways. In theory, this is what you are looking for; I actually cannot reproduce the behavior, as on my machine, QGIS behaves as expected with that option turned off (default is evaluated at save time). A sequence will indeed get incremented regardless of a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`; whenever the client application opens a transaction with an `INSERT` (`nextval` fires), the sequence will increment.